# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'survey_responses'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

After changing a couple of things in my Django app (unfortunately, I forgot what exactly I've changed) I'm seeing this weird error message:

```
(hr-djang) ➜  hr_djang git:(data-isolation) ✗ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/hr-djang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/..../.virtualenvs/hr-djang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/..../.virtualenvs/hr-djang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/hr-djang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/..../.virtualenvs/hr-djang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/..../.virtualenvs/hr-djang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/..../.virtualenvs/hr-djang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/..../.virtualenvs/hr-djang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/hr-djang/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'survey_responses'
```

`survey_responses` if one of my installed apps in the Django project. I've commented out all mentioned all references to `survey_responses` except for the one in `installed_apps` but the error doesn't change. I'm a bit lost on what could cause this ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was simple. By some stroke of genius, I moved the entire folder for survey_responses into another folder ...